# Wrong Memory is displaying in task manager for Default and Named instance in Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, memory

I have installed 2 instances on a Sqlserver 2016.When the Performance of the server is degrading ,  i could see huge transactions are happening on the Default instance and there were no connections and a single small database in a named instance.But when i see in the task manager , i see the memory of the named instance is increasing drastically with no CPU and default instance remains idle with High CPU.

Comment: Can you add output of `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory`  for both the instances in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have Lock Pages In Memory for the "active but low memory" instance? Task manager only show a minuscule memory usage in this case. You can for instance look in the error log file (startup info) if lock pages are used.

So, there's nothing to "fix". You should look at the memory usage through something else then Task Manager. For instance sys.dm_os_process_memory (physical_memory_in_use_kb) or sys.dm_os_sys_info (committed_kb)

Comment: yes , Lock Pages In Memory is enabled.Can you please brief me how to fix this.

Comment: I added some text to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response .Lock pages in Memory hint clears my doubt. :)